# Can I use my Laptop as a LAN Hotspot for my PC?

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, lan, connection-sharing

I recently moved apartments and right now it isn't possible for me to directly connect my PC via Ethernet-cable to my router (and my PC also has no WLAN-adapter), so I was wondering if I could use my Laptop as a sort of hotspot but with a LAN connection to my PC?

I already managed to create a WLAN hotspot on my Laptop via netsh, but wasn't able to do it for a LAN connection.

**EDIT:**

since I didn't clarify it clearly enough:
I want to connect my laptop to the Internet via WiFi and then share this connection with my PC by connecting the PC to the laptop with a cable.

**EDIT 2:**

since I forgot to mention it: both my Laptop and my PC are running the latest versions of Windows 10 and the network adapter on my laptop is a Broadcom 802.11n with the latest drivers, netsh also says that my adapter is compatible for network sharing (can confirm since I already managed to create a new wireless hotspot)

**EDIT 3:**

since it's been asked, here are screenshots of my adapters. Unfortunatly they are in german but "gemeinsam genutzt" means "shared" or "used together" (you'll get the gist). The first picure shows my PC, the second my Laptop

[image: PC screenshot]

[image: Laptop screenshot]

Since it was also asked: my PC get's a IPv4 address of 192.168.137.220 with the Subnetmask of 24 and I am able to ping my Laptops IP Address 192.168.137.1 and no I am using the goodn ol' Windows Firewall without any changes to it.

Comment: Try setting up your PC as a network repeater using windows built in feature (if its Windows 10 1607 or later) or third part software such as connectify

Comment: What is a LAN hotspot even supposed to be? It’s a 1:1 type of connection. What do you really want to accomplish? Connect your PC to your WiFi network?

Comment: I think I know what you mean, but its long for me to illustrate in comments so let me put a draft answer, and please let me know if thats what you want or not :)

Comment: Look up "tethering".

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution to accomplish what you want is to use Internet Connection Sharing (ICS).

To enable ICS:

1. Open “Network and Sharing Center” (just search in Start Menu)
2. Select “Change adapter settings” from the left pane
3. Locate your wireless connection and open its properties (right-click → Properties)
4. On the “Sharing” tab, enable ICS – select your wired connection as the “Home networking connection”
5. Confirm. Windows will warn you that the home connection’s IP address will change.

You can now connect your PC to your laptop using a network cable. If neither of the devices is terribly ancient, any network cable will do.

Comment: already did that, unfortunatly it doesn't work...
my PC network adapter is a NVIDIA nForce 10/100 Mbps Ethernet, could be quite old but I guess it should work

Comment: What exactly does not work? Did you enable it successfully? Is the physical Ethernet connection working (look for LEDs, the connection state Windows reports)? Does your PC receive an IP address on its wired connection? It should be set to receive IP address and DNS servers automatically.

Comment: well I have no internet connection when opening a browser and am also unable to ping for example google.com, windows network center does say though that it is connected to a private network.
The adapter alson says, like on my laptop with the wireless connection, that it is a shared connection, under IPv4 properties of my PC network adapter is the radio button for automatic IP-adress checked.

Comment: So, in the connection status, did it receive an IP address in in the 192.168.137.2-254 range? Can you ping 192.168.137.1 (your laptop) from your PC? Do you have a third-party firewall software installed on your laptop? Could you perhaps provide a screenshot of where it says that it’s a shared connection? (You can add the screenshot to your question by editing it.)